# Python Regex expression for extracting hashtags from text

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I'm processing some tweets I mined during the election and I need to a way to extract hashtags from tweet text while accounting punctuation, non-unicode characters, etc while still retaining the hashtag in the outputted list.

For example, the orignal text from a tweet looks like:

I'm with HER! #NeverTrump #DumpTrump #imwithherðŸ‡ºðŸ‡¸ @ Williamsburg, Brooklyn

and when turned into a string in python (or even put into a code block on this site), the special characters near the end are changed, producing this:

```
"I'm with HER! #NeverTrump #DumpTrump #imwithherdY\xd8\xa7dY\xd8, @ Williamsburg, Brooklyn"
```

now I would like to parse the string to be turned into a list like this:

```
['#NeverTrump','#DumpTrump', '#imwithher']
```

I'm currently using this expression where str is the above string:

```
tokenizedTweet = re.findall(r'(?i)\#\w+', str, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

however, I'm getting this as output:

```
['#NeverTrump', '#DumpTrump', '#imwithherdY\xd8']
```

How would I account for 'dY\xd8' in my regex to exclude it?
I'm also open to other solutions not involving regex.

Comment: I think `#imwithherdY\xd8\xa7dY\xd8` is full hastag, not `'#imwithherdY\xd8'` or `'#imwithher'`. It gives `#imwithherdYØ§dYØ`

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but what's so special about the `dY`, how can we determine it from a regular word?

Comment: @SebastianProske edited my question to clarify why `dY` is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yah, about the solution not involving regex. ;)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import string 
tweets = []

a = "I'm with HER! #NeverTrump #DumpTrump #imwithherðŸ‡ºðŸ‡¸ @ Williamsburg, Brooklyn"

# filter for printable characters then
a = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, a))

print a

for tweet in a.split(' '):
    if tweet.startswith('#'):
        tweets.append(tweet.strip(','))

print tweets
```

and tada: ['#NeverTrump', '#DumpTrump', '#imwithher']

Comment: @furas, gives ['#NeverTrump', '#DumpTrump', '#imwithherdY\xd8\xa7dY\xd8']
now ^^

Comment: how about `!`, `?`, `.` and maybe other chars ?

Comment: @Lord_PedantenStein that's the same output OP currently has. How does this answer his question?

Comment: Yes i did not see what the OPs problem was. Now giving ['#NeverTrump', '#DumpTrump', '#imwithher'] but if you have bad characters like these in your string the bug might be somewhere else

Comment: @purelyp93 here you go and if #imwithherdY\xd8\xa7dY\xd8 was the intended hashtag, just skip the filter for printable characters