# Python regex search matching just one

Tags: python, regex, search

I'm facing a little issue with a regex. I need to find multiple items matching a regex. But for now I just find one match. For example :

```
match = "@oneTwittos + @twoTwittos and @ThreeTwittos"
res = re.search('@(.*?)\s', match)
```

But 'res' contain only '@oneTwittos' and I didn't know why.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: `re.findall()`?

Comment: Yes, but with `'@\S+'` pattern (if you use `@(\S+)`, `re.findall` will omit `@`). Also, see another approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622037/python-regex-expression-for-extracting-hashtags-from-text).

Comment: You're right, it's working with : `re.findall('@\S+',match)`. Thanks a lot :)